# Optimization of the McEliece crypto system

Tags: mceliece

In the normal McEliece proposal, the public key
G' = SGP is used, with S beeing non-singular, G Generator Matrix and P permutation Matrix

In the White Paper on McEliece with Binary Goppa Codes by Michiel Marcus and the lecture of Tanja Lange it says that you do not need P because you can just permute the support L and remember the sorting - that's fine, I understand that BUT

they also say that the matrix S is not needed by bringing the Generator Matrix in systematic form because gaussian elimination is the same as multiplying by a non-singular matrix

My question is how can I decode a message mG' + e if I have given g,L

- the decoding algorithm by Patterson assumes the form mG + e and returns e

### so I have two problems:

1. how can I use g,L to decode a Codeword m = mSG + e generated by SG instead of G to get e - do I interpret mS as a new message m' and the decoding works just fine and returns mS?

2.after getting m' = mS how can I calculate m because S is unknown

Is my assumption wrong, that S is not available,because if I store the transformation of G to systematic form encoded in a Matrix S then I can calculate m
BUT in the whitepaper they do not store the matrix S

for reference:
In the whitepaper it says
[image: private and public keys in mceliece]

Answer (score 1):

The Paterson decoding algorithm will work for cipher texts $\mathbf c=\mathbf m G'+\mathbf e$, because Paterson only needs you to know the correspondence between field elements and columns. This allows you to recover $\mathbf e$. Once you have recovered $\mathbf e$ you know $\mathbf mG'=\mathbf c-\mathbf e$. $G'$ is in systematic form, so just look at the first $k$ entries of $mG'$ you recover $m$.

Comment: Oh yeah you are  right - but how is it in the niederreiter version - there I have given H' = SHP and it is send c= SHm, with wt(m) <= t so I can decode correctly

But to decode I have to calculate first S^(-1) c  = Hm and then I can decode to m given the support 

but do I have to store S as a private key here or can I apply an analog trick like for the McEliece system

Comment: @fepaul With Niederreiter, we typically work with the parity check matrix of the code and if we use systematic forms (which correspond to the same $S$) for both the generator and parity check matrices, then they are equivalent up to glueing of an identity matrix. This the same trick applies

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!